# i get an error Uninitialized string offset: 2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to insert multiple row to database with laravel

This is my controller code

```
    $references = References::all();
    $ref_id = $request->ref_id;
    $value = $request->value;

    for ($i=1; $i<=count($references); $i++) { 
        $data_save = [
            'ref_id' => $ref_id[$i],
            'value' => $value[$i],
        ];

        DB::table('values')->insert($data_save);
    }

    return redirect('values')->with('success', 'Data created Successfully');
```

And this is my HTML code

```
 <form action="{{ url('value/store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('post')
    
    @foreach ($references as $item)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col sm-6 form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="{{$item->id}}">
                <input type="text" value="{{$item->name_ref}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col sm-6 form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="value">
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
 </form>
```

I have an error

> Uninitialized string offset: 2

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code from Shibon

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_id[]" value="{{$item->id}}">
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="value[]" value="{{$item->value}}">
```

In your controller

```
$ref_id = $request->ref_id;
$value = $request->value;

//array start from 0 & count the array for your ref_id not for all reference
for ($i=0; $i<count($ref_id); $i++) { 
    $data_save = [
        'ref_id' => $ref_id[$i],
        'value' => $value[$i],
    ];

    DB::table('values')->insert($data_save);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html code, you are passing a string for input ref_id,value

From PHP you are assigning the values of this value to a variable and trying to fetch this as array

```
                <input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="{{$item->id}}">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="value">
```

This needs to be something like this

```
                <input type="hidden" name="ref_id[]" value="{{$item->id}}">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="value[]" value="1">
```

The array index will start from 0 so the loop will be like this

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($references); $i++) {
```

It is good to do batch insert instead of inserting value inside loop

Comment: Share the result ```print_r($ref_id)``` before the loop